# Are there any basic immediate mode gui tutorials?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, imgui

I am trying to find any basic tutorial which could show me how could I do immediate mode gui. I know it is a really hard thing to make own gui. I have already tried to make retained gui (it ends up being very basic). I have been looking for any im gui tutorials for a long time, but could not find one. I've tried to read ImGui lib, but some things are hard to understand.

Do you have any vidoes, books, ...?

Could you give me some advices how could I make that type of gui.

I do not want to use external libs. I want to learn something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Dear ImGui readme has a couple of references:

*The Immediate Mode GUI paradigm may at first appear unusual to some users. This is mainly because "Retained Mode" GUIs have been so widespread and predominant. The following links can give you a better understanding about how Immediate Mode GUIs works.*

- [Johannes 'johno' Norneby's article](http://www.johno.se/book/imgui.html).
- [A presentation by Rickard Gustafsson and Johannes Algelind](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2011/course/TDA361/Advanced%20Computer%20Graphics/IMGUI.pdf).
- [Jari Komppa's tutorial on building an ImGui library](http://iki.fi/sol/imgui/).
- [Casey Muratori's original video that popularized the concept](https://mollyrocket.com/861).
- [Nicolas Guillemot's CppCon'16 flash-talk about Dear ImGui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSRJ1jZq90k).
- [Thierry Excoffier's Zero Memory Widget](http://perso.univ-lyon1.fr/thierry.excoffier/ZMW/).

Reading/watching all of those should give you a better understanding at how they work and how to implement yours.

Comment: Thank you, Omar! I'll look through all.